# Using ClassLoader.defineClassCond to get a Class object from bytes of a class created through ASM, NoClassDefFoundException?

Tags: java, class, assembly, noclassdeffounderror

I've generated a class by taking the bytes of a base class and accepting them through a custom class adapter. When I call define class on the bytes produced as a product of the base class I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/MyClassBase
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyClassBase
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 26 more
```

The base class has been loaded by a URLClassLoader from a jar. Is there some underlying method call in defineClass that is throwing the exception because it cannot locate the loaded class? How can I fix this?

Keep in mind that it won't be practical to load the base class a different way. As a parameter to the problem I would say assume that it must be loaded through a URLClassLoader from another jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to load modified bytecode that relies on com.example.MyClassBase via a ClassLoader that can't see that class. When you create your own ClassLoader instance to load your modified class, you should be [chaining it to an existing ClassLoader using its constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#ClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29) to establish a parent/child hierarchy of loaders, which helps avoid this exact problem.

Comment: The problem is it's not "my" ClassLoader and I don't see a practical (or easy) way to modifying how the ClassLoader that loads the base class is created or how it loads the base class. If I were to define the new class with the ClassLoader that loaded the base class would I have any more luck?

Comment: Confirmed, defining the class with the ClassLoader that loaded the base class fixed the ClassNotFoundException and therefore the NoClassDefFoundError. I don't know if that's exactly what you were hinting at in your answer, but your answer was what made me attempt that, so for that I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: I wasn't sure I fully understood your situation, but I think what you said is what I meant :) I'm glad it helped, one way or the other.